# ¿Cómo hago para aumentar un variable que tengo declarada const int y es un Array?

Tags: c++, pilas

Esto es lo que se me pide:

> La implementación del TAD Pila con arrays establece un tamaño máximo de la pila que se controla con la función `pilaLlena()`. Modificar la función de tal forma que cuando se llene la pila se amplíe el tamaño del array a justamente el doble de la capacidad actual.

Tengo la función que me valida si la pila está llena:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int maximo_pila = 5;

struct pila{
    int frente;
    int dato[maximo_pila];
}q;
//struct Pila q;

int iniciar(){
    q.frente = 0;
    return 0;
}

int llena(){
    return (q.frente == maximo_pila)? 1:0;
}

int vacia(){
    return(q.frente == 0)? 1:0;
    
}

void insertar(int x){
    if(llena()){
        cout<<"LA PILA ESTA LLENA \n";
        maximo_pila
        return;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"\nIngrese los Datos: ";
        cin>>x;
        q.frente++;
        q.dato[q.frente]=x;
    }
}

void mostrar(){
    if(vacia()){
        cout<<"LA PILA ESTA VACIA! \n";
        return;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Los Datos de la Pila: \n";
        for(int d=0;d<=q.frente;d++){
            cout<<q.dato[d]<<"\n";
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    iniciar();
    int y,opc;
    
    do{
        cout<<"--MENU--\n\n1.Insertar \n2:Mostrar \n3:Salir\n";
        cin>>opc;
        switch(opc){
            case 1: insertar(y); system("pause");break;
            case 2: mostrar();system("pause");break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }while(opc != 3);
    
    }
```

Lo que no sé, es como aumentar el valor de la variable `maximo_pila`¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Creo que deberías echarle un vistazo al concepto de [*memoria dinámica*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoria_din%C3%A1mica_(programaci%C3%B3n)), y luego ya pasar a sus [detalles bajo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B)). Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar a entender la respuesta, tienes que entender todo lo que está mal en tu pregunta:

- No tienes una variable `const int` que es una formación<sup>1</sup>, tienes una formación de `int` cuyo tamaño es `const int`:

  ```
      const int maximo_pila = 5;
   // ^^^^^^^^^ <---- La variable 'maximo_pila' es un entero (int) constante (const).

   struct pila{
       int frente;
       int dato[maximo_pila];
   //  ^^^ <---- La variable 'dato' es una formación de 'maximo_pila' elementos enteros (int).
   }q;
  ```
- No puedes ampliar el tamaño de la formación porque el tamaño está prefijado en tiempo de compilación y forma parte del tamaño del objeto `pila`. Si quieres una colección de datos que pueda variar de tamaño no debes usar formaciones.

Para tener una colección de datos que pueda cambiar durante la ejecución, usa un puntero:

```
int *dato = nullptr;
//  ^ <---- Puntero a entero (int), de momento 'dato' no tiene datos.
```

Puedes pedir memoria con el operador `new`:

```
dato = new int[maximo_pila] {};
//     \_/ \______________/ ^^ <--- Se inicializa con '0' porque la lista de datos está vacía.
//      |         |
//      |         \--- Son 'maximo_pila' enteros (int).
//      |
//      \---- Creamos memoria dinámica
```

Si quieres más memoria, sólo tienes que pedirla:

```
/* Borramos la memoria anterior, para evitar fugas
   ( https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria ) */
delete [] dato;
// Pedimos nueva memoria.
dato = new int[maximo_pila * 2] {};
```

Si haces las cosas así, tienes dos problemas:

1. Gestionar la memoria manualmente es molesto y propenso a errores.
2. Se pierden los datos anteriores.

Te propongo lo siguiente:

- Usa punteros inteligentes.
- No incluyas cabeceras que no usas.

  - Elimina `<stdlib.h>`, que además de no usarla es de C, no de C++.
- Estás en C++, usa la programación orientada a objetos.

  - Mueve las funciones de gestión de la pila dentro del objeto de la pila.

    - Así evitas tener que crear variables globales.
  - Los objetos pueden tener constructores.
- En C++ existe el tipo `bool` para lógica booleana, no uses enteros para ello.

```
struct pila
{
    using puntero = std::unique_ptr<int[]>;

    pila() : dato { std::make_unique<int[]>(maximo_pila) } {}
    bool llena() const { return frente == maximo_pila; }
    bool vacia() const { return frente == 0; }

    void insertar(int x)
    {
        if (llena())
        {
            // Nuevo buffer
            puntero nuevo = std::make_unique<int[]>(maximo_pila * 2);

            // Copiamos datos antiguos al nuevo bufer y lo intercambiamos
            std::copy(dato.get(), dato.get() + maximo_pila, nuevo.get());
            dato.swap(nuevo);

            // Ampliamos el maximo y anyadimos el dato nuevo
            maximo_pila *= 2;
            return insertar(x);
        }

        dato[frente++] = x;
    }

    void mostrar() const
    {
        for (int indice = 0; indice != frente; ++indice)
            std::cout << dato[indice] << '\n';
    }

private:
    int frente = 0;
    int maximo_pila = 5;
    puntero dato;
};
```

[Puede usarse así](https://tio.run/##tVPLktowEDxbXzHZHNYOG3ZDshfApFK5pvIDLEUJWxBVZEmRJQJF8e1kRjLPQ2ove5Pm0T3TLVXWfqwU16vD4b3UlQq1gLE0rXeCNxN2jjWiMW47YQxTofJgpeJsx7LQSr0CG7QXzkAJra@Hw6DlnyDm1rux1H46m4wYy6gjL2AINfcGdqmy4b/FPJV3pXnDN7IxcyovYA@7PcsWxihQSmgCqIxuPfY74YPTsHQCuaEs4aJxBMeuNa/kf7ueqJZlayNrkLoVznOX4yiwKViGC2ZyCXnHjZEYyh4f4WcQawOLsFwKR6GjBDrGy9esBx9gUJA0EfC7sZI3po36tMC1l6tAB9VhIpdwsAVlcFDkqniziB0EEOkqY7c5tfdXwufFA5zP0LvU5yFBphSOgACxtP3LbR5T57m@NValwYTqMHAIrre8ll00OhrbqOdqwxIGEb7T/aTwJrKS8pF5mgzp9WYo3QZTJ08aeozY0FmYPFkaB9EkqWtZoY9kY3d@V3bujqDXS7HiQqHgYTyOE09Tckb3@xd9n1itk2vuxZBlhH98J4ifApfLlfCM0aPxBDlie9Qt1UmdF/RDYqmlwv5p@6fi@v7p5j64uX@@uX@J9tj@SRxMX@1394PHLwqi9Tx9na9wR5lYRl@DK/uLU8T2j1/rJMQV2XMifzuu7m2gxPvD4R8):

```
    pila p;
    p.insertar(0);
    p.insertar(1);
    p.insertar(2);
    p.insertar(3);
    p.insertar(4);

    p.mostrar();
    // Ahora esta llena.
    std::cout << "La pila esta llena? " << std::boolalpha << p.llena() << '\n';

    p.insertar(5);
    p.mostrar();
    // Ahora no esta llena: creció.
    std::cout << "La pila esta llena? " << std::boolalpha << p.llena() << '\n';
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.